# Miles Away not updating on reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swift3

I have a tableview cell with a uilabel inside of it and its getting the distance between two points(the users current location and another point I choose). The problem is that when I change the point in my database and reload the tableview, the miles away in each cell updates. But when I change my current location in the simulator and reload the tableview, the miles away doesnt update. Here is my code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCell
cell.object = object
let currentLocation = CLLocation()
locManager.distanceFilter = 50
if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse ||
    CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways){
    let coordinate₀ = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(-41)!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(52.3)!)
    let coordinate₁ = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    let distanceInMeters = coordinate₀.distance(from: coordinate₁)
    if(distanceInMeters <= 1609)
    {
        cell.Distance.text = "\(Float(round(distanceInMeters * 3.28084)).cleanValue) ft"
    }
    else
    {
        cell.Distance.text = "\(Float(round(distanceInMeters / 1609)).cleanValue) mi"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to close and restart the simulator when you update your location, have you tried that?

Comment: @RashwanL First when I do that it sets back to the default location and second is that on an iPhone simulator, will it update if a users location changes when they reload the tableview or does a user have to restart the app

Comment: No the real device will work immediately when you change position, the simulator does not.

Comment: In the simulator set the location to something mobile like the 'Freeway Drive'. This way the location will update without you having to restart the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your `CLLocationManager` in your `viewController` and then in the `didUpdateLocations` you need reload your tableView

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class MyViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var LabelTest: UILabel!
    var manager = CLLocationManager()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //your default position
    var userLoc = CLLocation(latitude: 42.6977,longitude: 23.3219)
        {
        didSet{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    //**Your class implementation**/

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //**Your implementation*//

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userlocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
        self.userLoc = userlocation
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.object = object
        let currentLocation = self.userLoc

        let coordinate₀ = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(-41), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(52.3))
        let coordinate₁ = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        let distanceInMeters = coordinate₀.distance(from: coordinate₁)
        if(distanceInMeters <= 1609)
        {
            cell.Distance.text = "\(Float(round(distanceInMeters * 3.28084)).cleanValue) ft"
        }
        else
        {
            cell.Distance.text = "\(Float(round(distanceInMeters / 1609)).cleanValue) mi"
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps